# Embeds in ThingsBoard Dashboards

Tags: widget, embed, dashboard, thingsboard

I am just wondering if it is possible to create a Thingsboard dashbaord widget that contains custom HTML. Specifically, is it possible to embed other content in a dashboard using a custom widget of some sort?

My use case is that I want to embed a video or some other feed into the board (ref: [Video feed to ThingsBoard dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678942/video-feed-to-thingsboard-dashboard)) and I'm trying to find some alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create your own widgets and yes you can write your own HTML, CSS and Javascript for those widgets.

Check out the [Widgets Development Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/) to get started.